# How to convert cshtml code to aspx code?

Tags: asp.net, razor

This is the code i need to convert:

```
<p> 
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") 

 @using (Html.BeginForm()){    
     <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
    } 
</p>
```

Comment: means you want to convert above code from razor view engine to aspx view engine in mvc?????

Comment: @Hans....if need more help then plzz comment....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert above code from razor view engine to aspx view engine in mvc then **:-**

```
<p> 
<%:Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>   
     <p> Title: <%:Html.TextBox("SearchString")%> <br />   
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
<% } %>
</p>
```

**The basic difference between `razor and aspx view engine` is that `razor engine` use `@` for any server side code and `aspx engine` uses `<% %>` for server side code.**

## Note :

**If you are trying to convert above razor code to webforms aspx code then you cannot do that because in asp.net mvc we have only htmlhelpers or html tags and no server controls unlike asp.net webforms which have server side controls.**